# Maze solution ( algorithm of backtracking)

Tags: python, backtracking, maze

I'm trying to create a maze solution (The maze is the Prim function).
But I don't understand why my backtracking algorithm doesn't work.
Can anyone help me ?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def Laby_mur(x,y):
    M = np.ones((2*x+1,2*y+1))
    return(M)

def Prim(x,y):
    M = Laby_mur(x,y)
    (X,Y) = np.shape(M)
    a, b = 2*rand(x)+1, 2*rand(y)+1
    M[a][b] = 0
    V1 = []
    V = [[(a-2, b),(a,b)],[(a, b-2),(a,b)],[(a+2, b),(a,b)],[(a, b+2),(a,b)]]
    for i in V:
        i0 = i[0]
        if 0<i0[0]<X-1 and 0<i0[1]<Y-1:
            M[i[0],i[1]] = 2
            V1 += [i]
    V = V1
    V1 = []
    while V != []:
        c = rand(len(V))
        [a,b] = V[c]
        del V[c]
        M[a[0],a[1]] = 0
        M[b[0]+(a[0]-b[0])//2,b[1]+(a[1]-b[1])//2]=0    
        d = a[0]
        e = a[1]
        V += [[(d,e+2),(d,e)],[(d-2,e),(d,e)],[(d,e-2),(d,e)],[(d+2,e),(d,e)]]
        for i in V :
            i0 = i[0]
            if  0<i0[0]<X-1 and 0<i0[1]<Y-1 and M[i0[0],i0[1]] != 0:
                M[i0[0],i0[1]]=2
                V1+=[i] 
        V=V1
        V1=[]
    M[0,1]=0
    M[X-2, Y-1]=0
    return(M,(a,b), V)
```

So this is my function to create a maze.
The function Prim takes in input a couple (x,y) and create first a matrix which size is (2x+1)*(2y+1) and which is full of one (= wall). It chooses two random numbers (a,b) who are odder numbers (to avoid boxes on the side). On the coordinate case (a,b), we change 1 by 0 (= empty). We then make the list of neighbouring boxes which are two coordinate boxes from (a,b) and we check that no coordinate is out of the matrix. We choose randomly one of this adjacent (which are change to 2) boxes and we change this case to 0. After we break the wall that separates these two boxes. We repeat this process until there are no more 2 - boxes.

Now, this is my backtracking algorithm.
I have to go East as often as possible.

```
    
def initialisation(laby):
    laby[0][1]=0.5
    P = [(0,1)]
    return(laby,P)

print(initialisation(Prim(2,2))[0])
    
def  Vers_Est(laby, i, j, P):
    if laby[i][j] == 0:
        P += [(i,j+1)]
        laby[i][j+1] = 0.5
        i = i
        j = j+1
        return(True, laby, P)
    else :
        return(False, laby, P)
        
def  Vers_Ouest(laby, i, j, P):
    if laby[i][j] == 0:
        P += [(i,j-1)]
        laby[i][j-1] = 0.5
        i = i
        j = j-1
        return(True, laby, P)
    else :
        return(False, laby, P)

def  Vers_Sud(laby, i, j, P):
    if laby[i][j] == 0:
        P += [(i+1,j)]
        laby[i+1][j] = 0.5
        i = i+1
        j = j
        return(True, laby, P)
    else :
        return(False, laby, P)
    
def  Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P):
    if laby[i][j] == 0:
        P += [(i-1,j)]
        laby[i-1][j] = 0.5
        i = i-1
        j = j
        return(True, laby, P)
    else :
        return(False, laby, P)
```

Each function (Vers_Est, Vers_Ouest...) associate with 4 inputs (maze in its matrix form, i, j, P which is a list describing the way to get out of the maze), a triplet : (True if a move can be made to the East / West / South / North, laby who is the maze after the move, P with the coordinates of the displacement).

```
def Demi_tour_Est(laby, i, j, P):
    if Vers_Est(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
        if Vers_Ouest(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False:
            if Vers_Sud(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
                if Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0] == False:
                    if laby[i][j+1] == 0.5 :
                        P.remove[(i,j)]
                        laby[i][j] = 0.2
                        return(True,laby,P)
                    else :
                        return(False, laby, P)
                    
def Demi_tour_Ouest(laby, i, j, P):
    if Vers_Est(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
        if Vers_Ouest(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False:
            if Vers_Sud(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
                if Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0] == False:
                    if laby[i][j-1] == 0.5 :
                        P.remove[(i,j)]
                        laby[i][j] = 0.2
                        return(True,laby,P)
                    else :
                        return(False, laby, P)
        
def Demi_tour_Sud(laby, i, j, P):
    if Vers_Est(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
        if Vers_Ouest(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False:
            if Vers_Sud(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
                if Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0] == False:
                    if laby[i+1][j] == 0.5 :
                        P.remove[(i,j)]
                        laby[i][j] = 0.2
                        return(True,laby,P)
                    else :
                        return(False, laby, P)
                    
def Demi_tour_Nord(laby, i, j, P):
    if Vers_Est(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
        if Vers_Ouest(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False:
            if Vers_Sud(laby,i,j,P)[0] == False :
                if Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0] == False:
                    if laby[i-1][j] == 0.5 :
                        P.remove[(i,j)]
                        laby[i][j] = 0.2
                        return(True,laby,P)
                    else :
                        return(False, laby, P)
```

Each function (Demi_tour_Est, Demi_tour_Ouest ...) allows to turn around if no coordinates are empty around the place laby[i][j].

```
def backtracking(laby):
    M = initialisation(laby)[0]
    i = 0
    j = 1
    (X,Y) = np.shape(M)
    P = initialisation(laby)[1]
    while M[i][j] != M[X-2][Y-1] :
        if Vers_Est(laby, i, j, P)[0] :
            Vers_Est(laby, i, j, P)
        elif Vers_Ouest(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
            Vers_Ouest(laby, i, j, P)
        elif Vers_Sud(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
            Vers_Sud(laby, i, j, P)[0]
        elif Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
            Vers_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0]
        else :
            if Demi_tour_Est(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
                Demi_tour_Est(laby, i, j, P)
            elif Demi_tour_Ouest(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
                Demi_tour_Ouest(laby, i, j, P)
            elif Demi_tour_Sud(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
                Demi_tour_Sud(laby, i, j, P)
            elif Demi_tour_Nord(laby, i, j, P)[0]:
                Demi_tour_Nord(laby, i, j, P)
    return(laby,P)

print(backtracking(Prim(3,3)))
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

In the function Backtracking, I want to put in relation these functions to try to solve the labyrinth.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please explain how the maze is represented by the function Prim. What is the meaning of each value in the array M? What does each component of the function's return value mean?

Comment: @NirH. I complete the text to explain how the maze is represented (and return the Maze, the first random coordinate (a,b) and a empty list)